# Summing up time based on date

Tags: python, date, dataframe, time, sum

I have a dataframe that stores sleep data (both regular sleep and nap). Here are a few of the dataframe's columns:

- Start time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)
- End time (same format as above)
- Duration

I'm trying to figure out a way to sum up the hours of sleep per day. It would be easy to look at 'Start time' and sum up the times from the same date, but it would be tricky in a scenario where someone takes a nap in the middle of the day, but sleeps at 1am (because it would be considered the next day).

I would ideally like to consider sleep before 4am the next day to be the same day, if that makes sense (e.g., nap from 5:00-7:00pm on 9/25, sleep from 2:00-7:00am 9/26. Then the total amount of sleep for 9/25 is 7 hours).

Any tips/suggestions on how to get this to work?

Here's my idea (I'm still not proficient in Python yet so I am just going to put pseudocode here and there):

```
# Create a datetime
next_day = datetime.time(4, 0, 0)

# Create an iterator
bedtimes = iter(df['Start time'])

for i in bedtimes:

    # Get current and next sleep datetime
    cur = df['Start time'][i]
    next = df['Start time'][i+1]

    # If the next datetime in the iterator is a day after AND before
    # 4:00am, add the times of 'cur' and 'next' together

    # What if there is a scenario where the user takes 2 one hour naps during
    # the day? What is a good way to catch that scenario as well? Use a while 
    # loop?
    if (cur.date() < next.date()) & (next.time() < next_day):
        total = cur.time() + next.time()
        # Advance to the next iteration
        next(bedtimes, None)

        # Somehow in here, I would want the loop to skip an iteration if we 
        # summed 'cur' and 'next' together (since they are considered sleep 
        # from the same day. I am interested in calculating the amount of 
        # sleep PER day)
```

Please correct my syntax if it is wrong! The above is just an idea. If there are better ways, I would love to hear how it can be done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I notice you're not using the "End Time" field here - is there a reason why you can't just sum (End Time - Start Time) for every row in the dataframe? Or do you *only* have Start Time and have to figure everything else out from that?

Comment: Oh my bad! I totally forgot the 'Duration' column (calculated by subtracting the 'Start time' from 'End time'). I could use that to sum up the total sleep time. But I would still need to look at the next day's 'Start time' to determine whether to sum it with "today's" sleep or not

Comment: What I'd do is make a first pass through the dataframe and detect intervals that "crossed" the time boundary, and then *split them up* - for example, 10pm-6am, splitting at 4am, becomes two intervals: 10pm-4am, and 4am-6am. Then, you can loop through the dataframe again and simply add up "end - start" for everything on a given day, since you now have no intervals that span multiple days.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I was able to work this out after you gave me an idea. Thanks so much!